# Getting Error while loading the XSLT in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

When I try to load the XSLT I'm getting the below error
**`Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack`**

```
string xmlFilePath = Path.Combine(GetAssemblyDirectory(), "TestResult.xml");
string xslFilePath = Path.Combine(GetAssemblyDirectory(), "SingleTableTestResult.xslt");
 strResultSummary = strResultSummary.Replace(ProjectPath, ProjectName);
File.WriteAllText(xmlFilePath, strResultSummary, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

//get the formatted HTML Report tranformed via xslt
string reportFileData = GenerateTestReport(xmlFilePath, xslFilePath);

//gets the path of the running assembly directory
private static string GetAssemblyDirectory()
        {
            string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
            DashboardBaseLogger.dashBoardlogger.WriteInfo("Directory location: " + Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        }

//Generates the test report
private string GenerateTestReport(string XMLFilePath, string XSLFilePath)
        {
            string reportFilePath = string.Empty;
            XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            transform.Load(XSLFilePath); //Exception here
            reportFilePath = Path.Combine(GetAssemblyDirectory(), "TestResult.html");
            transform.Transform(XMLFilePath, reportFilePath);
            return reportFilePath;          
        }
```

Getting an exception here `transform.Load(XSLFilePath); //Getting an Exception here`

Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error that you wrote seem a normal debug message, not a Runtime exception. May you insert a try..catch and write the full exception?

Comment: In the Catch block I'm getting "System.Threading.ThreadAbort" Exception.

Comment: There is a innerexception?

Comment: All the exception properties like "Data, Source, Stacktrace, InnerException" shows that debug message

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it makes a difference.

```
   // Create the XsltSettings object with script enabled.
    XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(false,true);//By default, the XslCompiledTransform class disables support for the XSLT document() function and embedded scripting. This is a way to bypass it.
    XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    transform.Load(XSLFilePath, settings, new XmlUrlResolver() ); //Exception here
    reportFilePath = Path.Combine(GetAssemblyDirectory(), "TestResult.html");
    transform.Transform(XMLFilePath, reportFilePath);
    return reportFilePath;
```

More information here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f54faw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx